# $K, N < G$ and $|G:N|$ and $|K|$ coprime, then $K<N$. Group action argument?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

A common exercise in finite group theory is

> Suppose $G$ is a finite group with $K < G$, $N \lhd G$.
>   Suppose that $|K|$ and $|G : N|$ are coprime. Then $K < N$.

The normal way to attack this is to note that $|KN:N|$ is coprime to $|K|$, but it is also equal to $\frac{|K|}{|K \cap N|}$, so it divides $K$, so it is $1$.

I'm interested to know if this can be turned into a group action argument (e.g. let $K$ act on the cosets of $N$ and do some counting), or if this fact is inherently not group action-y.

In general I'm wondering if most non-trivial arguments in finite group theory can be converted to group action arguments without adding much complexity.

Comment: When $N$ is normal in $G$, $G/N$ is a group on which $K$ acts by translation (inherit from the action of $G$). An argument on orbit and stabilizer should be equivalent to what you said.

Comment: @QuangHoang I'm not seeing why this will work. It seems not to use that $N$ is normal...we could just as easily let $K$ act on cosets of $N$ in the absence of a group structure on $G/N$.

Comment: It's exactly the quotient argument disguised in group action form. And exactly what you asked :-)

Comment: @QuangHoang Well, on second thought, we can note that the stabilizer of $N$ under this action is $K \cap N$ because $N$ is a normal subgroup. Now we know that the orbit of $N$ is size $|K|/|K \cap N|$, but I can't see why we can conclude this is $1$ straightaway without some more counting of the type in the original argument. In particular it seems we need to say that $HK$ is a subgroup and use Lagrange's Theorem, which makes the group action kind of useless.